# Javascript regex and replace tag

Tags: javascript, regex

Javascript regex and replace :

Input : `[url]testing data[/url]`

Replace by : `<b>`

Result : `<b>testing data</b>`

I need regex for it. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.replace(/\[url\](.*)\[\/url\]/, '<b>$1</b>')
```

Comment: This soilution will merge 2 consecutive tags into one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: Test your solution on `[url]a[/url]b[url]a[/url]` string. Hardly, you intended this to work *that* way. `/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/g` works better in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Not regex, but this would be simple solution

```
input.replace("[url]","<b>").replace("[/url]","</b>");
```

Comment: One extra `[url]` (opening tag) will create extra html opening tag `<b>` ... and mess the style of the page.

Comment: @kirilloid: not true - replace will perform replacement only once (which is exactly what he was asking for), unless `g` regex modifier is used.

Comment: Ok, let bad example be `[/url]a[url]`.

Comment: @kirilloid: correct, but this doesn't match the requested input (see the question)